# Problems importing packages on Circle Ci Golang

Tags: go, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am using Circle CI to test my project. The project is a simple Go application consisting of a few packages and a main.go file. When referencing packages within my project I simply import them as "projectName/packageName" in the code. This works fine locally, however, when I push to git and it gets built on Circle CI I get the following errors.

> package crypto-compare-go/handlers: unrecognized import path
>   "crypto-compare-go/handlers" (import path does not begin with
>   hostname)

I fixed this by prepending github.com/myGitUsername/projectName to my local package imports, this means that when I'm developing locally If I change one of the packages within my project, I have to push to git, then pull to be able to use them even though they are all under the same parent project folder. This seems like a slow, very inefficient process.

Has anyone had this problem with Circle CI before?

Comment: Your dependencies must be resolvable. This means `go get` must work, or you can use vendoring. There's not really a third option.

Comment: Go get works fine for me locally, I would have thought as the packages are all within the same project it would resolve them fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "within the same project". `go get` has no concept of a "project".  When you try to fetch these packages, what errors do you get?

Comment: Your local filesystem should match the proper Go import path. Set it correctly locally and you'll be able to do the same on CircleCI and any other environment.

Answer (score 1):

> I fixed this by prepending github.com/myGitUsername/projectName to my local package imports, this means that when I'm developing locally If I change one of the packages within my project, I have to push to git, then pull to be able to use them even though they are all under the same parent project folder. This seems like a slow, very inefficient process.

Nope. You get this wrong. Your go will use the local `$GOPATH/src/github.com/myGitUsername/projectName` dir to compile. You access github.com only if you run `go get -u <package path>`. It is documented in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths).

> Note that you don't need to publish your code to a remote repository
>   before you can build it. It's just a good habit to organize your code
>   as if you will publish it someday. In practice you can choose any
>   arbitrary path name, as long as it is unique to the standard library
>   and greater Go ecosystem.